# display data dynamically in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a List of image urls which I have to check whether the url is responding or not. i am adding the url which is not responding to my gridview one by one . the problem is

when first not responding url is displaying in the `Gridview`, but when a subsequent invalid url is added, it is replacing the first. I need to display all `RemoveUrl`s in the Gridview

here is my code:

```
List<RemoveUrl> RemoveUrl = new List<ValidateURLOfHIIPSData.RemoveUrl>();

DataTable DtFpId = BusinessClass.GetHotelFPID();

 for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)

{               
     if (Session["RemoveUrl"] != null)

     {
         RemoveUrl = (List<RemoveUrl>)Session["RemoveUrl"];
     }
    RemoveUrl = BusinessClass.SearchImageUrl(i)/*checking url for valid or not;
    Session["RemoveUrl"] = RemoveUrl;
    gvRemovedUrl.DataSource = Session["RemoveUrl"];
    gvRemovedUrl.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: tell clearly wat you want

Comment: i want to add row one by one  to gridview dynamically with the list data

Comment: ok then bind the list  in ur gridview , wat problem u r facing??

Comment: see url is checking one by one , and if it found not responding url is then all info related to that url is collecting into list and then i am binding list to my gridview but its not showing all not responding url only its display the last founded url is showing in gridview .but i want to diaplay all not responding Url

Comment: yeah by looping you will get only last url ,  so you must add all the urls in a list and then bind it to the gridview outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

Each time you iterate through your `for` loop, you are setting your `RemoveUrl` list to be the value that is stored in `Session["RemoveUrl"]`. I don't think this is what you are after.

I have made some assumptions:

1. All urls to be tested are stored in `Session["RemoveUrl"]`
2. `BusinessClass.SearchImageUrl()` accepts a `RemoveUrl` object
3. `BusinessClass.SearchImageUrl()` returns a `RemoveUrl` object

If so, the following code will point you in the right direction. (untested)

```
DataTable DtFpId = BusinessClass.GetHotelFPID();

if (Session["RemoveUrl"] != null) {
    List<RemoveUrl> allUrls = (List<RemoveUrl>)Session["RemoveUrl"]; // set the list to be the values stored in your session - I assume these are the ones you want to verify?
    List<RemoveUrl> removeUrls = new List<ValidateURLOfHIIPSData.RemoveUrl>(); // a list of invalid urls

    for (int i = 0; i < allUrls.length; i++) { // iterate through your urls
        // check if valid and add to removeUrls list
        removeUrls.add(BusinessClass.SearchImageUrl(allUrls[i]))
    }

    gvRemovedUrl.DataSource = removeUrls;
    gvRemovedUrl.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Some notes: you should name your variables starting with a lower case (e.g. `List<RemoveUrl> removeUrls`). Databinding is best done after all your data has been collated - in this case, after the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank's .But in this case all removed url will display when the loop will complete. i don't want to do this i want to display removed url one by one i mean when it found invalid url , its will be dynamically add to gridview

Comment: In your sample, you are iterating through a `for` loop once (start at '1', finish at '2') so it may as well not be there. In my answer I am looping through the assumed set of urls and checking each one. In either case, the validation within the loop should not take long, so I don't see the benefit of calling `DataBind()` each time it iterates (without seeing more code or at least the context of your example).